# Access a single object in an angular component built on ngFor

Tags: arrays, angular, angular6, ngfor

I have an angular component as below which displays a list coming from the backend in the left navigation.

```
<div *ngFor="let navItem of navItemList" >
  <div style="height:24px; padding-top:7px">
   <a style="font-size: 10pt;color:#455A64; padding-left:18px;">
    <span
    style="font-weight: bold;"
    matTooltip="{{ navItem.name }} Reports"
    matTooltipPosition="right" >
    <i class="fa {{ navItem.icon }} fa-md" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    {{ navItem.name }}
    </span>
   </a>
  </div>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
</div>
```

Below is the .ts file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-nav-list',
  templateUrl: './child.nav.list.component.html'
})
export class ChildNavListComponent {
  @Input() icon = '';
  @Input() navItemList: Array<any>
constructor() {
 console.log( this.navItemList);
 }
}
```

I am using the above component in the parent component as below

In the TS file

```
 navItemList: Array<any> = [{name: 'Report1', icon: 'fa-file'}, { name: 'Report2',  icon: 'fa-file'}, { name: 'Report3',  icon: 'fa-file'}]
```

In the html

```
    <child-nav-list (click) = "reportsCLick($event)" [navItemList] = "navItemList$ | async" ></child-nav-list>
```

This is resulted as shown below.

[image]

So when I click one Report,I am unable to get the clicked object. How to acess the clicked object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `(click)` looks like it's on the list as a whole - instead, put it on the items in the nav list rather than the entire list.

```
<div *ngFor="let navItem of navItemList" (click)="onClickItem(navItem)">
  <div style="height:24px; padding-top:7px">
   <a style="font-size: 10pt;color:#455A64; padding-left:18px;">
    <span
    style="font-weight: bold;"
    matTooltip="{{ navItem.name }} Reports"
    matTooltipPosition="right" >
    <i class="fa {{ navItem.icon }} fa-md" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    {{ navItem.name }}
    </span>
   </a>
  </div>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
</div>
```

Then in your TS:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-nav-list',
  templateUrl: './child.nav.list.component.html'
})
export class ChildNavListComponent {
  @Input() icon = '';
  @Input() navItemList: Array<any>
constructor() {
 console.log( this.navItemList);
 }

 onClickItem(item) {
  console.log(item);
 }
}
```

Then you can use an `Output()` to pass the clicked item back out into your parent component.

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Set @Output EventEmitter on child

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'child-nav-list',
  templateUrl: './child.nav.list.component.html'
})
export class ChildNavListComponent {
  @Input() icon = '';
  @Input() navItemList: Array<any>;
  @Output() emitter: EventEmitter;

  constructor() {
   console.log( this.navItemList);
  }

  onClickItem(item){
    this.emitter.emit(item);
  }
}
```

Set child html with click event as **8ytan** said:

```html
 <div *ngFor="let navItem of navItemList" (click)="onClickItem(navItem)">
 ...
</div>
```

Set parent component function when event emitted;

```html
    <child-nav-list (emitter) = "reportsCLick($event)" [navItemList] = "navItemList$ | async" ></child-nav-list>
```